Mandelstams for $2\to 2\to 3$ process
2 initial particles become two other particles, from which one decays into 2. Let $p1$ and $p2$ be the momenta of the initial particles, $p3$ the momentum of the decaying particle, $p5$ and p6 the momenta of the decay products and p4 the momentum of the third final state particle. I define the "mandelstam variables" for this process as
$$s=(p1+p2)^2$$
$$t=(p1-p3)^2$$
$$u=(p1-p4)^2$$
$$v=(p1-p5)^2$$
$$w=(p2-p5)^2$$
As with the normal 2->2 Mandelstams, we have
$$s+t+u=p3^2$$
(massless particles). Note that now the particle with the momentum p3 is off shell.
My guestion is, is there another constraining equation apart from the one mentioned above? The equation above comes basically from the 4-momentum conservation p1+p2=p3+p4, so shouldn't there be an equation which comes from p3=p5+p6? I have been trying to find this equation for a while now but I'm running in circles.

what is the process? is it $1+2\rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 4 + 5$?, or $1+2\rightarrow 3 +4$ followed by $4\rightarrow 5+6$?

The second option.

So there is really no reason to do this, and you pick an odd-ball reaction that doesn't work very. Since I used to visit TJNAF, I'll use some examples. (OH, and my 1st QM class was taught by Stanley Mandelstam, so I am somewhat of an expert).
His variables, $(s, t, u)$ are all connected to external lines, and each mean something tree level, so for:
$$ e^++e^- \rightarrow e^++e^- $$
you have two processes:

On the left is $s$-channel: the squared-four momentum of the virtual photon is $s$, and ofc $s>0$.
The right is $t$-channel: the squared four momentum of the exchanged photon is $t<0$.
Meanwhile, in Møller scattering:

the left is $t$-channel, and because of the identical particles in the final state: you also have $u$-channel.
The Mandelstam variables capture everything a (tree-level) virtual photon can do. Moreover, they are useful because in QED, all the amplitudes are related by just swapping the appropriate Mandelstam variables.
In the real world, you might also do elastic $ep\rightarrow ep$ scattering, where you are only concerned with $t$-channel. Here it's called $Q^2=-t$, and it's the length scale on which the $\gamma^*$ probes the proton structure. Btw, that reaction is also written:
$$ p(e, e')p $$
which means you put an electron beam on a proton target, and detected the scattered electron. You did not detect the recoil proton, but you kinematically know it's all there is.
So, to get your question, consider inelastic $ep$ scattering:
$$ e(p, e')X $$
where $[e,p]$ gives you $s$, $[e, e']$ is $t$, what you want to know is: what is $X$.
(Note, it's traditional to call the electron (hadron) momenta $k$ ($p$) with primes in the final state, so you measure $(k, k', p)$ directly with:
$$ s = (k+p)^2 $$
$$ t = (k'-k)^2 $$
from which you can get
$$ u = (p'-k)^2 $$
Now here's the point: you don't really use $u$ in this situation. You use, wait for it: $W^2$ (I think it's squared...), with:
$$ W^2 = p'^2 $$
and look at cross section vs $W$:

(that was the best pic I could find).
So what we see here is that when $W=M_p$, there is a huge elastic scattering peak (on the right), and as $k'_0$, the scattered electron's energy goes down, more energy is dumped into the target. The 1st peak is the $\Delta^+$ baryon resonance around:
$$ W = M_{\Delta} \approx 1232\,{\rm MeV/c^2} $$
Moreover, the width of that peak tells you the Delta lifetime (short!). The other peaks are just more baryons.
Another reaction is pion photo production:

While the electro production was $t$-channel, this is $s$-channel:
$$ \gamma +p \rightarrow \Delta^+ \rightarrow p+\pi^0 $$
or
$$ \gamma +p \rightarrow \Delta^+ \rightarrow n+\pi^+ $$
which you can write:
$$ \gamma(p, \gamma'\gamma')p $$
$$ \gamma(p, \pi^+)p $$
The latter, you can just use $(s, t, u)$ if you detect the recoil pion. In the former, you would detect the two photons and compute:
$$ W_{\gamma\gamma} \rightarrow m_{\pi} $$
to know you made a pion.
Now a caveat, to tie it all together: the initial electro-production of pions, which I called $t$-channel, can be written:
$$ \gamma^* + p \rightarrow p + \pi^0 $$
which is now an $s$-channel process, which is a "beam" of virtual photons, $\gamma^*$.
The point is, $(s, t, u)$ have meaning as they are each associated with a class of processes: annihilation, scattering, scattering with particle exchange.
In processes with more complicated final states, there is no reason to extend the Mandelstam variable; rather, you use the invariant mass of detected particles to understand the intermediate state. The concept is very similar to $(s, t, u)$, as they are also the invariant masses (squared) of an intermediate virtual state.

does it answer the question?

@TanmoyPati Yes: the answer is, "This is the wrong question"

As far as I understood the answer, this was off topic. My interest with the variables I defined is purely calculational, I want to express dot products of momenta using them.
